# Qt SDK, Apwrapper: what is it, what does it do.

Tags: visual-studio, qt, networking

I have network connections blocked for visual studio.  After installing the Qt SDK with visual studio add in, I get an error message, failed to connected to AppWrapper. Uninstalled the SDK, and no more attempts to connect to AppWrapper.  What is the AppWrapper installed with Qt?  Why does it attempt to make a network connection when you open Visual Studio?

Comment: in my case, VS2010 with qt source 4.8 manual build and VS-Addin1.1.10. when start VS, it complains "Could not connect to AppWrapper, Please make sure TCP port 12005 is not blocked."

Comment: @HaiyuanLi Have you solved your problem? I'm getting the same error message, but I couldn't figure how to fix it.

Comment: @Yamaneko: Not really. well that's long time ago so that I cannot remember itexactly :-)  | currently I'm using the latest Qt5.3, that problem has removed anyway. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

create a file in dir: "C:\Program Files\Digia\Qt4VSAddin" with name :"qtappwrapper.exe.config"
and type:

```
<configuration>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This does not answer the question