# QtAppWrapper: Unable to find a runtime version

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, qt, initialization, runtime

Recently I build Qt 4.8.1 for Visual Studio 2010.

But when I open Visual Studio 2010, it says:

**"qtappwrapper.exe : .NET Framework Initialization Error - Unable to find a runtime version for this application"**

I am on Windows XP Professional SP3 and use Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate with SP1 installed.

(. NET Framework installed is 4.0)

Any help would be appreciated.

( Btw I read change logs for Qt Visual Studio Add-in saying it had removed dependencies on .NET version 3.5 )

Thanks,

Pankaj

Answer (score 0):

I've got the error. Please try to find there is a lack of a file qtappwrapper.exe.config on:
c:\Qt\Digia\Qt4VSAddin - a path regarding Qt4 addin for Visual Studio, depends where it was installed.

It should contains something like that:

`<configuration>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319" />
    </startup>
</configuration>`

It was missing after addin installation.

details:

[Qt SDK, Apwrapper: what is it, what does it do.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050959/qt-sdk-apwrapper-what-is-it-what-does-it-do)